# In hdfs why do nodes seem so unreliable?

Tags: hdfs

In [this article](https://data-flair.training/blogs/hadoop-hdfs-tutorial/) the author talks about data reliability: blocks are duplicated among the datanodes to ensure that data is preserved when a node crashes. I do understand the concept, but what would make a node crash ? Does this happen very often in practice ?

Comment: Fire, waterspill, corrupt hardware, power failure, human error, faulty hard drive  etc. It might not happen often, but if your data is precious, you want to make sure you do not lose it, even when a cathastrophe occurs - which it does more often the more data and servers you have. If you have 1000 servers, expect failures1000 times as ofen than if you have just 1 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hdfs uses commodity hardware i.e nodes are built upon cheap hardware to decrease the overall cost.

Keeping this in mind blocks are duplicated.